# Android Firebase push notification cant get Any collection data from Greece and France, But other countries do.

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

We add Firebase SDK to our APK，and use their Push notification ,But several days ago,We found that ,We cant get any data from France and Greece any more ,We have no idea about that ,Is there any people have the same problom?

[image]

And the data shows that

[image]